# Pirkei Avoth's definition of a Rasha might not be the worst of his kind

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof

So one of the Pirkei Avoth talks about how שֶׁלִּי שֶׁלִּי וְשֶׁלָּךְ שֶׁלָּךְ, זוֹ מִדָּה בֵינוֹנִית, וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים זוֹ מִדַּת סְדוֹם.
It also says that שֶׁלָּךְ שֶׁלִּי וְשֶׁלִּי שֶׁלִּי, רָשָׁע.
From the previous 2 statements, is it okay to conclude that there are 2 types of bad guys.....
One bad guy type being the 'Sodomite' type and the other bad guy type being the 'Rasha' type?
( Also, it seems that the Rasha type of a bad guy might be a little better off, since the Sodomite is totally damned cause he aint getting no Techiyath Ha-meitim )

Comment: Maybe it's a sign that this person is Rasha, not a definition of what is a Rasha

Comment: Please rewrite your question to include the full passage and restate the question about Rasha. The source says "one is a **commonplace** type which some call Sodomite type".

Comment: there are several other mishnas there which use the term rasha